# Conection profile for Fabric 1.4.1 + Raft

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I'm trying the new version of fabric 1.4.1, and wanted to use Raft as my consensus algorithm I follow all the steps in the byfn tutorial.

However, I don't understand how to configure the connection.json profile in order to include the new orderers for later usage on composer.

Could you please advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a connection profile with 1 Peer, 1 CA, and a 5 node Raft Ordering Service:

`{
    "name": "channel1",
    "description": "Network Description",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "org1msp"
    },
    "organizations": {
        "org1msp": {
            "mspid": "org1msp",
            "peers": [
                "<Peer IP>:32321"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "<CA IP>:31941"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "<Orderer 1 IP>:31685": {
            "url": "grpcs://<Orderer IP>:31685",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "<PEM Cert>"
            }
        },
        "<Orderer 2 IP>:30386": {
            "url": "grpcs://<Orderer IP>:30386",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "<PEM Cert>"
            }
        },
        "<Orderer 3 IP>:32522": {
            "url": "grpcs://<Orderer IP>:32522",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "<PEM Cert>"
            }
        },
        "<Orderer 4 IP>:31366": {
            "url": "grpcs://<Orderer IP>:31366",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "<PEM Cert>"
            }
        },
        "<Orderer 5 IP>:30116": {
            "url": "grpcs://<Orderer IP>:30116",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "<PEM Cert>"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "<Peer IP>:32321": {
            "url": "grpcs://<Peer IP>:32321",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "<PEM Cert>"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "<Peer IP>"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "<CA IP>:31941": {
            "url": "https://<CA IP>:31941",
            "caName": "ca",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "<PEM Cert>"
            }
        }
    }
}`